# Google Earth stops immediately after startup

Tags: google-earth

Are there more people who have problems with Google Earth 64-bit? I am an enthusiastic Ubuntu user. I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 64 bit. I have the Google Earth 64 bit deb file downloaded from https://www.google.nl/intl/nl/earth/download/ge/agree.html and installed.

If I then start Google Earth, the first screen appears and the program stops immediately and then disappears from the screen. If I start Google Earth from the terminal window I get the following error messages:

```
wim@wim-HP:~$ google-earth 
[0426/115831:ERROR:net_util.cc(2195)] Not implemented reached in bool net::HaveOnlyLoopbackAddresses() 
[0426/115831:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115831:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115831:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115831:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115832:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115833:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115833:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115833:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler. 
[0426/115833:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
```

Another crash happened while handling crash!

Who can help me? What's my Ubuntu missing? Or what should I install extra?

Comment: I found the solution. I got the answer at a Dutch forum site. First the lsb-core package has to be installed from the Ubuntu Software center. After that download and install the 64 bit deb file from Google Earth. That was the solution for me. Regards, Wim

Comment: I tried to remove google-earth then install lsb-coore and reinstall google-earth but still the same message

Comment: Could you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Install lsb in full not just only the core.
Use the Synaptic Package Manager and search for lsb, click lsb, install, apply, leave package manager

From https://www.google.nl/intl/en/earth/download/ge/agree.html

System requirements:

PC - Windows XP, Windows Vista, or Windows 7

Mac - Mac OS X 10.6.0 or later

Linux - LSB 4.0 (Linux Standard Base) libraries

Answer (score 1):

(Redacted) answer from the comments:

> First the `lsb-core` package has to be installed from the Ubuntu Software center. After that download and install the 64-bit `.deb` file from Google Earth.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me also. I found the solution was to disable networking, and then launch Google Earth. After it launches, re-enable networking.

I know, not ultimate solution, but it works!