# Google-Earth will not launch and autometically quit

Tags: google-earth

i have install Google earth version 7.1.4 in Ubuntu 15.10,  when am  going to run this application it is automatically quit i have tried to remove it configuration file from "~/.googleearth" when i have remove this directory this is working 2 to 3 minute fine, after 2 to 3 minute it's showing same issue.

Comment: Have you tried launching Google Earth from command line and seeing if any errors are printed?

Comment: I have tried this method but same issue facing.

Comment: Are there any errors printed after it quits though?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me also. I found the solution was to disable networking, and then launch Google Earth. After it launches, re-enable networking.

I know, not the ultimate solution, but it works!

Also see: [Google Earth stops immediately after startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614724/google-earth-stops-immediately-after-startup/748792#748792)

Comment: I have tried this method but same issue facing