# Unable to start google earth pro on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, google-earth

I installed Google earth pro stable on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. But when I start up the Google earth, it stuck after welcome tips dialogue. No earth, no map can be seen.

Comment: On new versions of Ubuntu GoogleEarth usually needs a few months to have everything.  Usually find a library missing to make it work.  Will need to google ubuntu googleearth not loading to find.

Comment: This link might help.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/614724/google-earth-stops-immediately-after-startup?rq=1

Comment: Works fine here on 20.04, downloaded from google site, installed with apt. Scroll  down page.. https://www.google.com/earth/versions/